# add only unique numbers to IS TABLE OF NUMBER in pl/sql

Tags: plsql, unique

i want to add (product) ids to a "table of numbers" in PL/SQL.
Is there a option to check if the table contains a specific number?

i created the table with:

`type list_of_produktid_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY binary_integer;`

now i iterate over a big table which contains some informations about the product.
This informatons, i need to group and order the products. So i can't use the "unique" keyword in the select clause

i need something like:

```sql
IF NOT list_of_produktid.contains(l_items(i).item_name) THEN
 list_of_produktid(list_of_produktid.count+1):=l_items(i).item_name;
END IF;
```

greetings

Comment: I'm confused - it looks like you're trying to store an ITEM_NAME in a TABLE OF NUMBER.  Is your ITEM_NAME a number?  ???

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry about the bad names of variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is - use SQL [multiset conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions006.htm). See also [Comparing Nested Tables with SQL Multiset Conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm) from [PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm).

An example:

```
declare
  subtype bar_t is pls_integer;
  type bar_list_t is table of bar_t;
  type foo_list_t is table of bar_list_t index by pls_integer;
  v_foos foo_list_t;
  v_find_me constant pls_integer := 3;
begin
  v_foos(1) := bar_list_t(1,3,5,7,9);
  v_foos(2) := bar_list_t(0,2,4,6,8);

  for i in v_foos.first .. v_foos.last loop
    if v_find_me member of v_foos(i) then
      dbms_output.put_line('value ' || v_find_me || ' is found from index ' || i);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Note that you can negate the logic with `not member of`.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this solution a try