# Checking against a whitelist efficiently in plsql

Tags: sql, plsql

I need to validate a given input string against a whitelist which is the output of a select statement. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Example:

```
WhiteList -- { select distinct object_type from dba_objects; }  
Input -- 'my_input_varchar'
```

Now I need to check if `my_input_varchar` is present in the whitelist above.

I am looking for an optimal solution since this validation will be done many times from my code and firing the select query as given in whitelist above will be a performance overhead.

Kindly let me know your suggestions.

Though the below is not correct, this is my requirement:

```
declare  
    c_type varchar2(100) := 'QUEUE';  
begin  
    If c_type IN (select distinct object_type from dba_objects) then  
        dbms_output.put_line('YES');  
    else  
        dbms_output.put_line('NO');  
    end if;  
end;
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that involves querying `dba_objects` data dictionary view that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? You could use something like:

```
DECLARE
    c_type VARCHAR2(100) := 'QUEUE';
    v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1)
    INTO v_count
    FROM dual
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dba_objects WHERE object_type = c_type);

  IF v_count > 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('YES');  
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('NO');  
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways... As I understand you have a predefined SQL statement that you cannot change and you want to work on the output.

You can try loading the data to a collection. Even though a loop is used it is still an efficient solution. The data is collected only once and it exists in the memory.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR select_stmt_cur IS
        -- your query
        SELECT  object_type
        FROM    user_objects;

    TYPE select_stmt_ntt IS TABLE OF select_stmt_cur%ROWTYPE;
    l_select_stmt  select_stmt_ntt;

    FUNCTION if_exists(input_in IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN
    AS
    BEGIN
        FOR indx IN l_select_stmt.FIRST..l_select_stmt.LAST LOOP
            IF l_select_stmt(indx).object_type = input_in THEN
                RETURN TRUE;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        RETURN FALSE;
    END if_exists;
BEGIN
    OPEN  select_stmt_cur;
    FETCH select_stmt_cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_select_stmt;
    CLOSE select_stmt_cur;

    IF if_exists('PACKAGE') THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YES');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: **Do not write explicit loop** but use [Multiset Conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions006.htm) instead ! See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17938728/272735) SO question.